# Improve the performance of recursive sampling function

Tags: r, dataframe, performance, sampling

As a follow-up to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70882770/efficient-recursive-random-sampling-with-groups-of-unequal-size), I'm interested in improving the performance of the existing recursive sampling function.

By recursive sampling I mean randomly choosing up to n unique unexposed IDs for a given exposed ID, and then randomly choosing up to n unique unexposed IDs from the remaining unexposed IDs for another exposed ID. If there are no remaining unexposed IDs for a given exposed ID, then the exposed ID is left out.

The original function is as follows:

```
recursive_sample <- function(data, n) {
 
 groups <- unique(data[["exposed"]])
 out <- data.frame(exposed = character(), unexposed = character())
 
 for (group in groups) {
  
  chosen <- data %>%
   filter(exposed == group,
          !unexposed %in% out$unexposed) %>%
   group_by(unexposed) %>%
   slice(1) %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   sample_n(size = min(n, nrow(.))) 
  
  out <- rbind(out, chosen)
  
 }
 
 out
 
}
```

I was able to create a more efficient one as follows:

```
recursive_sample2 <- function(data, n) {
 
 groups <- unique(data[["exposed"]])
 out <- tibble(exposed = integer(), unexposed = integer())
 
 for (group in groups) {
  
  chosen <- data %>%
   filter(exposed == group,
          !unexposed %in% out$unexposed) %>%
   filter(!duplicated(unexposed)) %>%
   sample_n(size = min(n, nrow(.))) 
  
  out <- bind_rows(out, chosen)
  
 }
 
 out
 
}
```

Sample data and bechmarking:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- tibble(exposed = rep(1:100, each = 100),
             unexposed = sample(1:7000, 10000, replace = TRUE))

microbenchmark(f1 = recursive_sample(df, 5),
               f2 = recursive_sample2(df, 5),
               times = 10)

Unit: milliseconds
 expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval cld
   f1 1307.7198 1316.5276 1379.0533 1371.3952 1416.6360 1540.955    10   b
   f2  839.0086  865.2547  914.8327  901.2288  970.9518 1036.170    10  a
```

However, for my actual dataset, I would need an even more efficient (i.e., quicker) function. Any ideas for a more efficient version, whether in `data.table`, involving parallelisation or other approaches are welcome.

**December 2023 edit**

The versions from @minem and @ThomasIsCoding are substantially faster; however, they return only partially correct results. Considering sample data such as:

```
df <- structure(list(exposed = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
                                 2L, 2L, 2L), unexposed = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 10L, 4L, 5L, 
                                                            7L, 8L, 9L), rowid = 1:12), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
                                                                                                                            "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"))

   exposed unexposed rowid
1        4         1     1
2        4         2     2
3        4         2     3
4        1         1     4
5        1         2     5
6        1         3     6
7        3        10     7
8        2         4     8
9        2         5     9
10       2         7    10
11       2         8    11
12       2         9    12
```

I would expect exposed == 4 to be sampled twice, exposed == 1 to be sampled once, exposed == 3 to be sampled once, and exposed == 2 to be sampled twice. **In other words, the sampling procedure should reflect the provided order of data.** Desired output:

```
exposed unexposed rowid
1        4         1     1
2        4         2     2
6        1         3     6
7        3        10     7
8        2         4     8
11       2         8    11
```

Comment: A reproducible example would be helpful.

Comment: i don't see any recursion here?  can you explain what the function is supposed to do?

Comment: @ George Savva recursive might not be the perfect way to describe this process, I agree. In essence, the function should sample up to n unique unexposed IDs for each exposed ID, but in a step-wise fashion. This means sampling up to n unique unexposed IDs for one exposed ID and then sampling up to n unexposed IDs from the remaining unexposed IDs for another exposed ID. If there are no remaining unexposed IDs for a given exposed ID, then the exposed ID is left out.

Comment: I guess "Dynamic Programming" (DP) seems more accurate for your question, since you need dynamically adapt your sampling according to your previous actions.

Comment: I suggest you have a self-contained data example and expected output as well, and rephrase "recursive" to something else to avoid misunderstand.

Comment: what if your data is `df <- df[-c(4,5),]`, where `df` is your latest update? What would be the output? Should the algorithm start from `exposed == 1`?

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding in that case, exposed == 1 should not be present in the final dataset. The procedure should follow the initial data order.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and now I got it. I updated my solutions.

Comment: @tmfmnk, I notice that `recursive_sample2` never selects row 3 in the example data. Is this the desired behavior, or should it be randomly selecting either row 2 or row 3 (in addition to always selecting row 1 for `n = 2`)? `fminem` below behaves the same as `recursive_sample2`, but `ftic` will randomly select either row 2 or row 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Updated 12/13/23

A `data.table` solution that keeps a running list of sampled values and uses `%!in%` from `collapse` to prevent them from being sampled again:

```
library(data.table)
library(collapse) # for %!in%

fjblood1 <- function(data, n) {
  setDT(data)
  # randomly select unique exposed/unexposed rows
  u <- 1:nrow(data)
  if (anyDuplicated(data, by = c("exposed", "unexposed"))) {
    u <- u[
      data[,i := .I][
        sample(.N), -i[duplicated(.SD)], .SDcols = c("exposed", "unexposed")
      ]
    ]
    data[,i := NULL]
  } 
  sampled <- vector(mode(data$unexposed), length(u))
  k <- 0L
  data[
    u, .(
      unexposed = {
        x <- unexposed[unexposed %!in% sampled[seq_len(k)]]
        x <- x[sample.int(length(x), min(length(x), n))]
        sampled[seq.int(k + 1L, along.with = x)] <- x
        k <- k + length(x)
        x
      }
    ), exposed
  ]
}
```

Alternatively, if `df` has additional columns that you want to preserve:

```
fjblood2 <- function(data, n) {
  setDT(data)
  u <- 1:nrow(data)
  if (anyDuplicated(data, by = c("exposed", "unexposed"))) {
    u <- u[
      data[,i := .I][
        sample(.N), -i[duplicated(.SD)], .SDcols = c("exposed", "unexposed")
      ]
    ]
    data[,i := NULL]
  } 
  sampled <- vector(mode(data$unexposed), length(u))
  k <- 0L
  data[
    u, {
      i <- which(unexposed %!in% sampled[seq_len(k)])
      i <- i[sample.int(length(i), min(length(i), n))]
      sampled[seq.int(k + 1L, along.with = i)] <- unexposed[i]
      k <- k + length(i)
      .SD[i]
    }, exposed
  ]
}
```

Other candidate functions:

```
ftmfmnk <- function(data, n) {
  groups <- unique(data[["exposed"]])
  out <- tibble(exposed = integer(), unexposed = integer())
  
  for (group in groups) {
    chosen <- data %>%
      filter(
        exposed == group,
        !unexposed %in% out$unexposed
      ) %>%
      filter(!duplicated(unexposed)) %>%
      sample_n(size = min(n, nrow(.)))
    
    out <- bind_rows(out, chosen)
  }
  
  out
}

fminem <- function(data, n) {
  groups <- unique(data[["exposed"]])
  # working on vectors is faster
  id <- 1:nrow(data)
  i <- vector("integer")
  unexposed2 <- vector(class(data$unexposed))
  ex <- data$exposed
  ux <- data$unexposed
  
  for (group in groups) {
    f1 <- ex == group # first filter
    f2 <- !ux[f1] %in% unexposed2 # 2nd filter (only on those that match 1st)
    id3 <- id[f1][f2][!duplicated(ux[f1][f2])] # check duplicates only on needed
    # and select necesary row ids
    is <- sample(id3, size = min(length(id3), n)) # sample row ids
    i <- c(i, is) # add to list
    unexposed2 <- ux[i] # resave unexposed2
  }
  out <- data[i, ] # only one data.frame subset
  out$id <- NULL
  out
}

ftic <- function(df, n) {
  lst <- split(df, ~exposed)[as.character(unique(df$exposed))]
  pool <- c()
  for (k in seq_along(lst)) {
    d <- lst[[k]]
    dd <- subset(d[sample.int(nrow(d)), ], !duplicated(unexposed) & !unexposed %in% pool)
    lst[[k]] <- head(dd, n)
    pool <- c(pool, dd$unexposed)
  }
  `rownames<-`(do.call(rbind, lst), NULL)
}

`%nin%` <- function (x, table) {
  match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) == 0L
}

fmnist_fast <- function(dat, n) {
  # make a named vector
  vec <- setNames(dat$unexposed, dat$exposed)
  
  # Randomly shuffle the groups
  ord <- unique(names(vec))
  
  # random order the vector
  vec <- sample(vec, size = length(vec))
  
  # keep the names for sampling and later
  nms <- names(vec)
  
  
  # note that there is no need to sample again since both the order 
  # of the groups as well as the order within the groups (vec) was sampled.
  
  # by setting an initial value, we avoid an exception in the first iteration
  init <- head(unique(vec[nms == ord[1]]), n)
  
  # `unique()` drops the names 
  # yet names are needed to retain the initial data structure
  names(init) <- rep(ord[1], length(init))
  
  res <- Reduce(
    \(x, y) {
      # current subgroup
      vec_sub <- vec[nms == y]
      
      # without unique, duplicated values inside of the group 
      # can be selected multiple times
      res_vec <- head(unique(vec_sub[vec_sub %nin% x]), n)
      
      # in case all values of the current group are already sampled
      len_vec <- length(res_vec)
      if (len_vec == 0) {
        return(x)
      }
      
      # `unique()` drops the names 
      # yet names are needed to retain the initial data structure
      names(res_vec) <- rep(y, len_vec)
      
      # concate
      return(c(x, res_vec))
    },
    # first group is already in init
    ord[-1], 
    # first group, randomly sampled (see above)
    init = init
  )
  
  # back to a data.frame
  res_dat <- data.frame(exposed   = names(res),
                        unexposed = res)
  return(res_dat)
}
```

Compare the results from the dataset in the question (with two additional columns to demonstrate `fjblood2`):

```
df <- data.frame(exposed = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
                 unexposed = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 10L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 9L),
                 rowid = 1:12)

dt <- as.data.table(df)
fjblood1(dt, 2L)
#>    exposed unexposed
#> 1:       4         1
#> 2:       4         2
#> 3:       1         3
#> 4:       3        10
#> 5:       2         4
#> 6:       2         7
fjblood2(dt, 2L)
#>    exposed unexposed rowid
#> 1:       4         2     3
#> 2:       4         1     1
#> 3:       1         3     6
#> 4:       3        10     7
#> 5:       2         8    11
#> 6:       2         9    12
ftmfmnk(df, 2L)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>   exposed unexposed rowid
#>     <int>     <int> <int>
#> 1       4         1     1
#> 2       4         2     2
#> 3       1         3     6
#> 4       3        10     7
#> 5       2         4     8
#> 6       2         9    12
fminem(df, 2L)
#>    exposed unexposed rowid
#> 1        4         1     1
#> 2        4         2     2
#> 3        4         2     3
#> 5        1         2     5
#> 10       2         7    10
#> 9        2         5     9
fmnist_fast(df, 2L)
#>   exposed unexposed
#> 1       4         2
#> 2       4         1
#> 3       1         3
#> 4       3        10
#> 5       2         5
#> 6       2         8
ftic(df, 2L)
#>   exposed unexposed rowid
#> 1       4         2     3
#> 2       4         1     1
#> 3       1         3     6
#> 4       3        10     7
#> 5       2         7    10
#> 6       2         5     9
```

As pointed out in the updated question, `fminem` does not behave as desired.

Benchmarking with a larger dataset:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- tibble(
  exposed = rep(1:1000, each = 1000),
  unexposed = sample(7e4, 1e6, 1),
  data1 = runif(1e6),
  data2 = sample(LETTERS, 1e6, 1)
)
dt <- as.data.table(df)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  ftmfmnk = ftmfmnk(df, 100L),
  fminem = fminem(df, 100L),
  ftic = ftic(df, 100L),
  fmnist_fast(df, 100L),
  fjblood1 = fjblood1(dt, 100L),
  fjblood2 = fjblood2(dt, 100L),
  times = 1
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>                   expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
#>                ftmfmnk 74362.9330 74362.9330 74362.9330 74362.9330 74362.9330 74362.9330     1
#>                 fminem  5675.6071  5675.6071  5675.6071  5675.6071  5675.6071  5675.6071     1
#>                   ftic  4624.8753  4624.8753  4624.8753  4624.8753  4624.8753  4624.8753     1
#>  fmnist_fast(df, 100L) 16919.1535 16919.1535 16919.1535 16919.1535 16919.1535 16919.1535     1
#>               fjblood1   943.9751   943.9751   943.9751   943.9751   943.9751   943.9751     1
#>               fjblood2   909.6813   909.6813   909.6813   909.6813   909.6813   909.6813     1
```

Another benchmark with more replications and excluding `ftmfmnk`:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  # ftmfmnk = ftmfmnk(df, 100L),
  fminem = fminem(df, 100L),
  ftic = ftic(df, 100L),
  fmnist_fast(df, 100L),
  fjblood1 = fjblood1(dt, 100L),
  fjblood2 = fjblood2(dt, 100L),
  times = 10
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>                   expr        min         lq       mean    median         uq        max neval
#>                 fminem  5518.5713  5550.8040  5614.1822  5600.498  5615.9687  5788.3764    10
#>                   ftic  4370.4639  4412.8366  4467.5108  4434.879  4558.6254  4607.8332    10
#>  fmnist_fast(df, 100L) 16483.5461 16524.7059 16639.4094 16602.269 16708.1953 17001.8668    10
#>               fjblood1   618.8821   628.6334   644.4724   636.097   646.6322   693.7889    10
#>               fjblood2   707.1110   730.6251   756.7017   754.079   788.2097   814.0123    10
```

Comment: You should be aware that the set operations are relatively slow, so you should be able to achieve some performance gain if you replace `setdiff` by some expression with `%in%`. Anyway, nice `data.table` approach, +1!

Comment: Thanks for the prod. That matches with my somewhat vague memory. I updated with `%!in%` from collapse for a bit of a speedup.

Comment: This is a beautifully concise piece of code, thank you very much :) The only issue with the fjblood2 option is that it can return the same unexposed ID twice. For example, in exposed == 4, it can return unexposed == 2 twice. A given unexposed ID should be present only once (as one row) in the final dataset.

Comment: Here is one example with 1000 seeds: `table(map_lgl(.x = 1:1000,
              function(seed) {
               set.seed(seed) 
               fjblood2(df, 2) %>%
                count(exposed, unexposed) %>%
                summarise(cond = any(n != 1)) %>%
                pull(cond)
              }
))`. It does occur in about 1/3 of runs.

Comment: @tmfmnk, I got `FALSE 1000` when I ran that code. Are you sure you are using the current version of `fjblood2`?

Comment: This is quite a curious case! I tried it in a new session and I am still able to get unexposed == 2 twice for exposed == 4.

Comment: Surprising that `ftic2` becomes a disaster when the dataset scales up. Anyway, it's a super interesting finding, cheers!

Comment: Ah, I see it now! In your initial data, you do not have the same unexposed ID present multiple times in one exposed ID. Please see the sample data I provided in the question.

Comment: Thanks for tracking that down--I didn't notice the most recent update to the question. I will plan on addressing that tomorrow.

Comment: I apologize for not providing a clear description of the problem in the initial post. I realized some of the edge cases later on. Thanks a lot for your help regardless :)

Comment: @tmfmnk, it's been updated. The easiest and fastest thing was to randomly remove duplicates prior to the sequential sampling.

Comment: I've done extensive testing, and your solution works just about fantastically both in terms of speed and handling of edge cases! Thank you very much for this :)

Answer (score 5):

*The codes below are for previous questions and old datasets. For the up-to-date solution with the latest updates in both question and dataset, please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77649516/12158757).*

---

## ***Disclaimer***

I (personally) prefer coding with base R and here are some options, since I believe base R helps to understand the mechanism under the hood and also possible to achieve considerable efficiency even without additional packages.

And of course, if you ***pursue the pure speed only***, you should refer to other advanced packages and corresponding approaches as well, like [what @jblood did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76407647/12158757).

---

## Base R options

- `Reduce`

```
ftic1 <- function(data, n) {
    Reduce(
        \(x, y) {
            rbind(x, head(subset(y, !unexposed %in% x$unexposed), n))
        },
        split(data[sample(1:nrow(data)), ], ~exposed)[as.character(unique(data$exposed))]
    )
}
```

- `for` loop: version 1

```
ftic2 <- function(data, n) {
    with(
        data,
        {
            v <- unique(exposed)
            lst <- vector("list", length(v))
            q <- c()
            for (k in seq_along(v)) {
                p <- unexposed[(!unexposed %in% q) & exposed == v[k]]
                if (length(p) == 0) {
                    lst[[k]] <- NULL
                } else {
                    u <- head(p[sample.int(length(p))], n)
                    lst[[k]] <- cbind(exposed = v[k], unexposed = u)
                    q <- c(q, u)
                }
            }
            as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lst))
        }
    )
}
```

- `for` loop: version 2

```
ftic3 <- function(data, n) {
    lst <- with(data, split(unexposed, exposed)[as.character(unique(exposed))])
    pool <- c()
    for (k in seq_along(lst)) {
        v <- lst[[k]]
        u <- v[!v %in% pool]
        lst[k] <- ifelse(length(u) > n, list(sample(u, n)), list(u))
        pool <- c(pool, lst[[k]])
    }
    type.convert(setNames(rev(stack(lst)), names(data)), as.is = TRUE)
}
```

---

## Output Example

With `df` given from OP's question

```
> ftic1(df, 2)
   exposed unexposed
1        4         1
2        4         2
5        1         3
6        3        10
10       2         8
8        2         5

> ftic2(df, 2)
  exposed unexposed
1       4         1
2       4         2
3       1         3
4       3        10
5       2         7
6       2         4

> ftic3(df, 2)
  exposed unexposed
1       4         1
2       4         2
3       1         3
4       3        10
5       2         9
6       2         8
```

---

## Benchmarking (with different dataset sizes)

Approaches are listed as below

```
fjblood1 <- function(data, n) {
    setDT(data)
    sampled <- vector(mode(data$unexposed), nrow(data))
    k <- 0L
    data[
        , .(
            unexposed = {
                x <- unexposed[unexposed %!in% sampled[seq_len(k)]]
                x <- x[sample.int(length(x), min(length(x), n))]
                sampled[seq.int(k + 1L, along.with = x)] <- x
                k <- k + length(x)
                x
            }
        ), exposed
    ]
}

fjblood2 <- function(data, n) {
    setDT(data)
    sampled <- vector(mode(data$unexposed), nrow(data))
    k <- 0L
    data[
        ,
        {
            i <- which(unexposed %!in% sampled[seq_len(k)])
            i <- i[sample.int(length(i), min(length(i), n))]
            sampled[seq.int(k + 1L, along.with = i)] <- unexposed[i]
            k <- k + length(i)
            .SD[i]
        },
        exposed
    ]
}

ftmfmnk <- function(data, n) {
    groups <- unique(data[["exposed"]])
    out <- tibble(exposed = integer(), unexposed = integer())

    for (group in groups) {
        chosen <- data %>%
            filter(
                exposed == group,
                !unexposed %in% out$unexposed
            ) %>%
            filter(!duplicated(unexposed)) %>%
            sample_n(size = min(n, nrow(.)))

        out <- bind_rows(out, chosen)
    }

    out
}

fminem <- function(data, n) {
    groups <- unique(data[["exposed"]])
    # working on vectors is faster
    id <- 1:nrow(data)
    i <- vector("integer")
    unexposed2 <- vector(class(data$unexposed))
    ex <- data$exposed
    ux <- data$unexposed

    for (group in groups) {
        f1 <- ex == group # first filter
        f2 <- !ux[f1] %in% unexposed2 # 2nd filter (only on those that match 1st)
        id3 <- id[f1][f2][!duplicated(ux[f1][f2])] # check duplicates only on needed
        # and select necesary row ids
        is <- sample(id3, size = min(length(id3), n)) # sample row ids
        i <- c(i, is) # add to list
        unexposed2 <- ux[i] # resave unexposed2
    }
    out <- data[i, ] # only one data.frame subset
    out$id <- NULL
    out
}


ftic1 <- function(data, n) {
    Reduce(
        \(x, y) {
            rbind(x, head(subset(y, !unexposed %in% x$unexposed), n))
        },
        split(data[sample(1:nrow(data)), ], ~exposed)[as.character(unique(data$exposed))]
    )
}

ftic2 <- function(data, n) {
    with(
        data,
        {
            v <- unique(exposed)
            lst <- vector("list", length(v))
            q <- c()
            for (k in seq_along(v)) {
                p <- unexposed[(!unexposed %in% q) & exposed == v[k]]
                if (length(p) == 0) {
                    lst[[k]] <- NULL
                } else {
                    u <- head(p[sample.int(length(p))], n)
                    lst[[k]] <- cbind(exposed = v[k], unexposed = u)
                    q <- c(q, u)
                }
            }
            as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lst))
        }
    )
}

ftic3 <- function(data, n) {
    lst <- with(data, split(unexposed, exposed)[as.character(unique(exposed))])
    pool <- c()
    for (k in seq_along(lst)) {
        v <- lst[[k]]
        u <- v[!v %in% pool]
        lst[k] <- ifelse(length(u) > n, list(sample(u, n)), list(u))
        pool <- c(pool, lst[[k]])
    }
    type.convert(setNames(rev(stack(lst)), names(data)), as.is = TRUE)
}
```

- Small size

With the dataset given in the updated question, we run the following benchmarking script

```
df <- structure(
    list(exposed = c(
        4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
        2L, 2L
    ), unexposed = c(
        1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 10L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 8L,
        9L
    )),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
        "1", "2", "3", "4",
        "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"
    )
)
n <- 2
dt <- as.data.table(df)
microbenchmark(
    fjblood1 = fjblood1(dt, n),
    fjblood2 = fjblood2(dt, n),
    fminem = fminem(df, n),
    ftmfmnk = ftmfmnk(df, n),
    ftic1 = ftic1(df, n),
    ftic2 = ftic2(df, n),
    ftic3 = ftic3(df,n),
    unit = "relative"
)
```

which gives

```
Unit: relative
     expr         min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
 fjblood1   6.4168151  5.142746  5.714648  5.137915  5.182090 21.810226   100
 fjblood2  10.2215142  8.260134  9.204300  8.501112  8.128708 22.865106   100
   fminem   0.9815306  1.075249  1.996025  1.091704  1.052034 31.366451   100
  ftmfmnk 116.7095553 98.740732 92.170153 95.355659 85.750936 73.738831   100
    ftic1   8.7822192  7.385250  7.638289  7.132669  6.762140 18.621511   100
    ftic2   1.0000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000   100
    ftic3   4.2110394  4.059356  4.015434  4.008809  3.705119  8.273886   100
```

- Big size

```
set.seed(123)
df <- tibble(
    exposed = rep(1:1000, each = 1000),
    unexposed = c(replicate(1e3, sample(7e4, 1e3)))
)
dt <- as.data.table(df)
n <- 2L
microbenchmark(
    fjblood1 = fjblood1(dt, n),
    fjblood2 = fjblood2(dt, n),
    ftic1 = ftic1(df, n),
    ftic2 = ftic2(df, n),
    ftic3 = ftic3(df, n),
    times = 10L,
    unit = "relative"
)
```

shows

```
Unit: relative
     expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq         max
 fjblood1   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.0000000
 fjblood2   2.771467   2.472605   2.360890   2.563041   2.723441   1.3771934
    ftic1  10.580318  12.251636   9.301784  10.176871  10.005448   5.2545817
    ftic2 557.732618 556.806101 417.405326 462.315480 417.127467 206.5138370
    ftic3   1.628257   1.514933   1.423689   1.720916   1.607287   0.7996517
 neval
    10
    10
    10
    10
    10
```

- Bigger size

```
set.seed(123)
df <- tibble(
    exposed = rep(1:1000, each = 1000),
    unexposed = c(replicate(1e3, sample(7e4, 1e3)))
)
dt <- as.data.table(df)
n <- 100L
microbenchmark(
    fjblood1 = fjblood1(dt, n),
    ftic3 = ftic3(df, n),
    times = 20L,
    unit = "relative"
)
```

shows

```
Unit: relative
     expr      min       lq     mean   median      uq      max neval
 fjblood1 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.00000 1.000000    20
    ftic3 5.955011 5.107471 4.364985 4.545183 4.01909 3.064281    20
```

Comment: Thank you for all the solutions :) `ftic1` works really well without additional columns; however, with more columns, it can both return the same unexposed ID in one exposed ID twice or sample more than the specified n of unexposed IDs. `ftic2` and `ftic3` can return the same unexposed ID in one exposed ID twice.

Comment: @tmfmnk could you share the data where `ftic2` and `ftic3` failed, say, duplicated `unexposed` IDs?

Comment: Please see the updated sample dataset in the question. It's the case of exposed == 4 and the occurrences of two unexposed == 2 in this exposed ID.

Comment: @tmfmnk I just saw your latest update with `rowid` column. You can check my solution in a new post https://stackoverflow.com/a/77649516/12158757

Answer (score 2):

Working on vectors is much faster:

```
recursive_sample3 <- function(data, n) {
  groups <- unique(data[["exposed"]])
  # working on vectors is faster
  id <- 1:nrow(data)
  i <- vector('integer')
  unexposed2 <- vector(class(data$unexposed))
  ex <- data$exposed
  ux <- data$unexposed
  
  for (group in groups) {
    f1 <- ex == group # first filter
    f2 <- !ux[f1] %in% unexposed2 # 2nd filter (only on those that match 1st)
    id3 <- id[f1][f2][!duplicated(ux[f1][f2])] # check duplicates only on needed
    # and select necesary row ids
    is <- sample(id3, size = min(length(id3), n)) # sample row ids
    i <- c(i, is) # add to list
    unexposed2 <- ux[i] # resave unexposed2
  }
  out <- data[i, ] # only one data.frame subset
  out$id <- NULL
  out
}
```

benchmarks:

```
microbenchmark(f1 = recursive_sample(df, 5),
               f2 = recursive_sample2(df, 5),
               f3 = recursive_sample3(df, 5),
               times = 3)
# Unit: milliseconds
# expr       min        lq        mean    median         uq       max neval cld
#   f1 1399.8988 1407.1939 1422.008133 1414.4889 1433.06280 1451.6367     3 a  
#   f2  667.0813  673.7229  678.106400  680.3645  683.61895  686.8734     3  b 
#   f3    6.2399    6.2625    9.531267    6.2851   11.17695   16.0688     3   c
```

Iterating on `recursive_sample3` & incorporating concerns of `sample`:

```
f_minem <- function(data, n) {
  i <- vector('integer')
  unexposed2 <- vector(class(data$unexposed))
  ux <- data$unexposed
  exl <- split(1:nrow(data), data$exposed)
  for (ii in exl) {
    f2 <- !ux[ii] %in% unexposed2
    f12 <- ii[f2]
    dn <- !duplicated(ux[f12])
    id3 <- f12[dn]
    is <- id3[sample.int(min(length(id3), n))]
    i <- c(i, is)
    unexposed2 <- ux[i]
  }
  out <- data[i, ]
  out
}
```

benchmarks nr2:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  recursive_sample3 = recursive_sample3(df, 5L),
  recursive_sample4 = recursive_sample4(setDT(df), 5L),
  f_minem = f_minem(df, 5L),
  setup = {df <- copy(data)}
  , times = 10
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#              expr    min     lq    mean  median      uq     max neval cld
# recursive_sample3 6.2102 6.2974 9.63296 6.43245 16.3367 17.0746    10  a 
# recursive_sample4 3.5145 3.6249 3.67077 3.67075  3.7513  3.7970    10   b
#           f_minem 2.1705 2.1920 2.27510 2.23215  2.3784  2.4585    10   b
```

Comment: This solution is incredibly fast on my actual data. Thanks a lot for this :)

Answer (score 2):

#### Fixed Function

First, I fixed the answer from thomasiscoding because it had two bugs:

1. `split` sorts its result alphabetically, hence why 4 never was selected
2. the initial value in `Reduce`, `x`, has always been all items of the first group.

```
fmnist <- function(dat, n) {
  
  # randomply order the data
  data_split <- split(dat[sample(nrow(dat)), ], ~exposed)
  
  # randomly sort the groups because split orders the result by its names
  # there lied the reason that 4 has never been sampled
  data_split <- data_split[sample(names(data_split))]
  
  # for the initial value, get the first n values. 
  # Otherwise, the first group would be fully selected
  data_split[[1]] <- head(data_split[[1]], n)
  
  # rekursive function
  Reduce(
    \(x, y) {
      rbind(x, head(subset(y, !unexposed %in% x$unexposed), n))
    },
    data_split,
  )
}
```

#### New Function

Furthermore, I developed a new function that avoids the bottleneck `rbind`. instead, it uses a named vector and creates the data.frame just before the return.

```
`%nin%` <- function (x, table) {
  match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) == 0L
}

fmnist_fast <- function(dat, n) {
  # make a named vector
  vec <- setNames(dat$unexposed, dat$exposed)

  # Randomly shuffle the groups
  ord <- unique(names(vec))
  
  # random order the vector
  vec <- sample(vec, size = length(vec))
  
  # keep the names for sampling and later
  nms <- names(vec)
  
  
  # note that there is no need to sample again since both the order 
  # of the groups as well as the order within the groups (vec) was sampled.
  
  # by setting an initial value, we avoid an exception in the first iteration
  init <- head(unique(vec[nms == ord[1]]), n)
  
  # `unique()` drops the names 
  # yet names are needed to retain the initial data structure
  names(init) <- rep(ord[1], length(init))
  
  res <- Reduce(
    \(x, y) {
      # current subgroup
      vec_sub <- vec[nms == y]
      
      # without unique, duplicated values inside of the group 
      # can be selected multiple times
      res_vec <- head(unique(vec_sub[vec_sub %nin% x]), n)
      
      # in case all values of the current group are already sampled
      len_vec <- length(res_vec)
      if (len_vec == 0) {
        return(x)
      }
      
      # `unique()` drops the names 
      # yet names are needed to retain the initial data structure
      names(res_vec) <- rep(y, len_vec)
      
      # concate
      return(c(x, res_vec))
    },
    # first group is already in init
    ord[-1], 
    # first group, randomly sampled (see above)
    init = init
  )
  
  # back to a data.frame
  res_dat <- data.frame(exposed   = names(res),
                        unexposed = res)
  return(res_dat)
}
```

#### Proof of Concept

```
df <- data.frame(exposed   = c(4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
                 unexposed = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 10L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 9L))

set.seed(3)

# One Value
fmnist_fast(dat = df, n = 1)
#>   exposed unexposed
#> 4       4         2
#> 1       1         3
#> 3       3        10
#> 2       2         8

# Two Values
fmnist_fast(dat = df, n = 2)
#>   exposed unexposed
#> 1       4         2
#> 2       4         1
#> 3       1         3
#> 4       3        10
#> 5       2         5
#> 6       2         9

# Five Values
fmnist_fast(dat = df, n = 5)
#>   exposed unexposed
#> 1       4         2
#> 2       4         1
#> 3       1         3
#> 4       3        10
#> 5       2         5
#> 6       2         9
#> 7       2         8
#> 8       2         7
#> 9       2         4
```

#### Performance Test & Check

```
set.seed(123)
df <- tibble(
  exposed = rep(1:100, each = 100),
  unexposed = sample(1:7000, 10000, replace = TRUE)
)
mbm <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  recursive_sample2 = recursive_sample2(df, 5),
  ftic              = ftic(df, 5),
  fmnist            = fmnist(df, 5),
  fmnist_fast       = fmnist_fast(df, 5),
  times = 10
)

mbm
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>               expr    min     lq  mean median     uq    max neval
#>  recursive_sample2 135.65 137.95 143.3 141.89 149.45 157.71    10
#>               ftic  11.45  12.05  13.2  12.84  14.14  17.36    10
#>             fmnist  11.50  11.72  13.5  13.53  15.16  16.24    10
#>        fmnist_fast   8.95   9.02   9.2   9.17   9.34   9.51    10

# function works - no duplicated values
res <-  lapply(1:100, function(x){
  set.seed(x)
  anyDuplicated(fmnist_fast(df, 5)$unexposed)
})
unique(res)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 0
```

Comment: This is an improvement compared with the previous ones, thank you. The only issue is that it still does ignore the initial order of data. Fro this reason, it is not ensured that exposed == 4 will actually end up in the sampled data when n = 2.

Comment: Ah I thought that was desired. Easy, just exclude the sample() around names(). I updated the answer but I dont have the time rn to run the full code again so that code and output matches.

Comment: Thank you for additional changes. Considering the initial order and n = 2, exposed == 4 should be present in the final data always twice. Then, for exposed == 1, there should be only one remaining unexposed ID (and this should be 3). This is because unexposed == 1 OR 2 were already selected for exposed == 4.

Comment: Okay, I updated it that the order of the groups is mirrored in the result

Comment: Thank you, this works fantastically :) One follow-up question, is there a straightforward way to expand it so that it would return all the additional potential columns present in the initial dataset? In other words, that it would return the entire chosen row.

Comment: Does `anyDuplicated(df[, c("exposed", "unexposed")])` return `0`? If so, a simple inner join would work. Otherwise, one could still merge and just randomly select the corresponding row inside of the group.

Comment: It does, there are no duplicates in this sample dataset. In my real data, there can be two or more occurrences of the same unexposed ID in one exposed ID, and these denote distinct cases. Ideally, the function would return the entire row or at least the row ID from the initial dataset.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is good idea to edit anything further in [my existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76406414/12158757) (it has been accumulated based on many iterations of updates) , in case that someone would like to read about the base R options, the difference in their implementations and performance. So, let's just leave them as they are there.

---

To respond to OP's latest update, here again comes a base R option, which could deal with more than `2` columns.

```
ftic <- function(df, n) {
    lst <- split(df, ~exposed)[as.character(unique(df$exposed))]
    pool <- c()
    for (k in seq_along(lst)) {
        d <- lst[[k]]
        dd <- subset(d[sample.int(nrow(d)), ], !duplicated(unexposed) & !unexposed %in% pool)
        lst[[k]] <- head(dd, n)
        pool <- c(pool, dd$unexposed)
    }
    `rownames<-`(do.call(rbind, lst), NULL)
}
```

such that

```
> ftic(df, 2L)
  exposed unexposed rowid
1       4         1     1
2       4         2     2
3       1         3     6
4       3        10     7
5       2         8    11
6       2         5     9
```

## Idea Behind

The duplicates in `unexposed` are pre-processed, i.e., being shuffled and in turn removed, before starting the sampling procedure in the iterative `for`-loop.

Comment: This solution is really concise and handles all edge cases well: I awarded the bounty  to the other one only because that is even faster on my actual data. Thanks a lot for your help :)